# Firing a timer in a background app and showing UILocalNotifications

Tags: iphone, ios4, background-process, uilocalnotification

I've written an iPhone app to display available bandwidth for my satellite modem, but I'm interested in allowing the timer to continue to fire in the background (though with much greater time between ticks) and display UILocalNotifications during events such as reaching a 20% remaining limit. I think the answer to this is "You can't", but I'm posting here just in case I'm wrong.

PS: Stack Overflow always shows up first on my Google Searches. You've got a very great community here. Thank you for all your help. :)

Comment: Accepting that it's probably impossible right now, I filed an enhancement request. I'd suggest that any other developers would duplicate this so Apple notices it's a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently impossible, but a "known issue" being investigated by Apple's engineers.

Comment: Have you heard anything back on that from Apple? What would be the solution?

Comment: Their resoponse was that it's a duplicate known issue. It leads me to believe we'll see this functionality introduced in a later iOS revision, probably quietly.